# Does anyone meet this error while using DesktopAppConverter to convert win32 to uwp?

Tags: uwp, desktop-app-converter

I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter to package an application that doesn't have an installer. But it always prompts the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 :
Exception calling "Compile" with "0" argument(s): "Reference to undeclared attribute group
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/preview/windows10/msixappcompatsupport:PreviewEntryPointAttributesGroup'."
```

I don't know where does it "Reference to undeclared attribute group"

and sry for my bad English:(

Comment: Hello, when you perform Desktop-Bridge conversion, you need to check whether there are unsupported APIs in your application. You can read this document to check: [Prepare to package a desktop application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare)

Comment: Hello, the error message you showed seems to be sent by `DesktopAppConverter`. This shows that an exception occurred during the conversion process. During the process of converting Win32 applications to UWP applications, some APIs are not supported, and errors will occur during the conversion process. You can check the application project first and exclude unsupported APIs before converting. P.S. StackOverflow is an English forum, and communication in English is recommended here :)

Comment: kk, I'll  check it

Comment: thx very much :)

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? I am facing the same problem after a system update.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem which involves modifying the DesktopAppConverter tool itself.

To do this you need to change the owner of the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps folder from SYSTEM to your user account (See https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00688470/), and then open the folder "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util" and change Line 196 of ManifestOps.ps1 from

```
$manifest = [AppxManifest]::new($ManifestDir, $schemaPath)
```

to

```
 $manifest = [AppxManifest]::new($ManifestDir, $installedSchemaPath)
```

After making this change, the DesktopAppConverter worked for me and produced a valid .appx file as output.

Remember to change the owner of the WindowsApps folder back to SYSTEM when you're done.